# Laravel 9 + VS Code: Undefined method intelephense(1013)

Tags: vscode-extensions, laravel-9

I'm getting this intelephense error in vscode (linux), but the code is actually working.

Controller:
[image]

\App\Models\User.php:
[image]

\App\Models\Listings.php:
[image]

my listings migration:
[image]

Both with thinker and in the view I get a proper response so I have no idea what triggers this error. I'd like to get rid of it so I'm not always distracted by these errors. I'm not very experienced with Laravel so I have no idea whether I'm doing anything wrong, missing some kind of extension or if this is a bug.

Not sure how to proceed with this as it's working.
I was following the Laravel 9 tutorial from Traversy media on Youtube. He uses a Mac and doesn't get the error, also has the same php intelephense extension.

Comment: I have a similar situation to yours.
I'm working with VSCode and using SQLite.
At some point I recall:
echo "My Error Message" . .$db->lastErrorMsg();

When calling the lastErrorMsg function, VSCode also reports the error:
Undefined method 'lastErrorMsg'.intelephense(1013)

And even in this case the code works perfectly, as the function is also described in the official documentation.
More precisely here, in the official PHP documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.lasterrormsg

So I don't understand but I guess it's a bug of VSCode, if someone can explain us better.